# Android/Xamarin Audio Recording/Encoding

Tags: android, audio, encoding, xamarin, recording

I'm currently coding an Android application with Xamarin and I'm using the AudioRecord class to record my audio.

```
audioRecord = new AudioRecord (
            // Hardware source of recording.
            AudioSource.Mic,
            // Frequency
            11025,
            // Mono or stereo
            ChannelIn.Mono,
            // Audio encoding
            Android.Media.Encoding.Pcm16bit,
            // Length of the audio clip.
            audioBuffer.Length
        );
```

But when it comes to choosing an Audio encoding, `Android.Media.Encoding` only has 4 options

```
Android.Media.Encoding.Default
Android.Media.Encoding.Invalid
Android.Media.Encoding.Pcm8bit
Android.Media.Encoding.Pcm16bit
```

`MediaRecorder` seems to have some [more options](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/media/MediaRecorder.AudioEncoder.html) but no GSM option.

**So here are my questions:**

**1)** Does anyone know of another recording option for android besides `AudioRecord` and `MediaRecorder` since neither seem to allow GSM by default? Maybe something in the `Android.Net.Rtp` API since it already has a GSM codec?

**2)** Or does anyone know a way to encode/decode audio to/from GSM using any of the current audio formats android lets you record to/play from?

*Alternative:* I could also be open to changing GSM to another format of similar size and quality to which I'm getting clear voice transmission at a rate of about 2 KB/s. However, that will require me to change my WinForms Desktop application which utilizes NAudio. So suggestions here are welcome if there is a good solution, however it would be better to find a solution to one of my other two questions.

Comment: No, `AudioRecord` gives you uncompressed PCM. And I don't think `MediaRecorder` allows for GSM compression either. You'll probably have to find an external GSM codec implementation and bundle it with your app.